# Replacements for "i.e." other than "that is"

Tags: word-choice

I frequently write technical texts, in particular mathematics. As the subject matter tends to be difficult, I have made it a habit to augment each potentially confusing phrase with a clarification. The abbreviation *i.e.* has become my trusted tool for this task.

However, I have never been very satisfied with *i.e.*, mostly because I am beginning to use it like a unique grammatical construct, even though it is just an abbreviation. My problem is that I find the commonly cited synonym "that is" to be *worse*, I think it breaks the flow of sentences too much.

Let me demonstrate this with a typical example

> Assume that this is not true, i.e. that there are counterexamples X and Y such that the statements `Y < X` and `X < 2Y` are false.

If I want to replace "i.e." by "that is", I have to remove the second "that"

> Assume that this is not true, that is there are counterexamples X and Y such that the statements `Y < X` and `X < 2Y` are false.

but I find this version to be less readable than the original. The reason is that the *i.e.* invites the reader to repeat the preceding clause, i.e. the reader can enhance the flow by reading it as follows:

> Assume that this is not true, i.e. (*assume*) that there are counterexamples X and Y such that the statements `Y < X` and `X < 2Y` are false.

If I wanted to enhance readability with "that is", I would have to repeat a part of the first clause explicitely in the text

> Assume that this is not true, that is *assume that* there are counterexamples X and Y such that the statements `Y < X` and `X < 2Y` are false.

Such explicit repetition would grow old really fast, though.

The underlying problem seems to be that the phrase "that is" carries no meaning by itself, it is again a shorthand for "which means that", "this says that" or "in other words".

My question is:

What are other alternatives to *i.e.* that can I use in the sentence above?

Comment: I would assert that you probably often could (and should) break up your sentences into shorter sentences: Assume that this is not true. Assume that there are counterexamples X and Y, such that the statements Y < X and X < 2Y are false.

Comment: @JLG: Alas, the reformulation you offer changes the meaning slightly, with the unfortunate effect that your version becomes very confusing. My audience will understand this as "Assume something. Assume something else." and will take a while to figure out that these two assumptions are actually the same. That's why I need the conjunction "i.e.".

Comment: Maybe: Assume that this is not true; assume that there are counterexamples X and Y, such that the statements Y < X and X < 2Y are false.

Answer (score 6):

What about ***namely***?

> Assume that this is not true, ***namely***, that there are counterexamples X and Y such that the statements `Y < X` and `X < 2Y` are false.
>
> Assume that this is not true--***namely***, that there are counterexamples X and Y such that the statements `Y < X` and `X < 2Y` are false.

Some recommend you [use a dash if a comma comes after "namely,"](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/blog.php?action=ViewBlogArticle&ba_id=160) but I think it's redundant since the dash signifies namely.

Comment: I like that. I use *namely* a lot, but never made the connection with *i.e.*. It does seem to have a slightly different connotation, though. "I want to eat a tasty bubble gum, namely the pink one." vs "I want to eat a tasty bubble gum, i.e. the pink one." In the first case, there could also be a green gum that is tasty, while the second sentence implies that only the pink gum is tasty.

Comment: A question concerning punctuation: in your sentence, I would omit the comma after *namely*. Which punctuation is preferable?

Comment: In the math example, the commas on both sides of namely are parenthetical commas, so both are necessary (don't omit). In the bubble gum example, you are using namely to clarify a direct object (not a clause), so you don't need the comma.

Comment: Yes, use both commas, as that makes it more readable. In fact, in your examples above, an extra comma would help solve your problem: "_Assume that this is not true, that is, assume that there are counterexamples X and Y..._" (You can see that same construct illustrated [here](http://books.google.com/books?id=KlJNp_hUmEIC&pg=PA249&dq=%22that+is+that%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=gfG8T4ZJyrXoAdKaxD8&ved=0CEYQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=%22that%20is%20that%22&f=false))

Answer (score 2):

What you could do is use punctuation. I think I prefer a dash, but colon and comma could work.

> Assume that this is not true: that there are counterexamples X and Y such that the statements `Y < X` and `X < 2Y` are false.
>
> Assume that this is not true, that there are counterexamples X and Y such that the statements `Y < X` and `X < 2Y` are false.
>
> Assume that this is not true — that there are counterexamples X and Y such that the statements `Y < X` and `X < 2Y` are false.

Or vary your phrase as you suggested, or break it up into shorter sentences, or a combination of methods throughout the document. In this particular case, I got to "such that" and had to go back and read the first part again.

Comment: I really like the dash. Are there any formal rules for its use, like for the colon or semicolon? So far, I have avoided the dash because I do not know how to use it.

Answer (score 1):

**In other words** is a fairly standard replacement for *i.e* and *that is*.

In other words, I use that phrase whenever I wish not to use *i.e* or *that is*.

Answer (score 0):

I write many technical papers and I also find sometimes challenging the use of "i.e.", especially because I am against the use of acronyms, and that is to avoid misunderstanding by non-native English speakers.  I agree that "i.e." is a very good "tool" to allow further elaboration of a complex text.  For this reason, I tend to use "in other words" rather than "i.e." but also "for clarity" in place of "in other words" to also avoid being repetitive in texts that require multiple clarifications of a statement.

Suggestion:
in other words;
for clarity;
and for clarity.

In practice:
Assume that this is not true, and for clarity, that there are counterexamples X and Y such that the statements Y < X and X < 2Y are false.

Assume that this is not true, in other words, that there are counterexamples X and Y such that the statements Y < X and X < 2Y are false.

I hope that helps.

Comment: In the sentence [‘one meal, i.e., breakfast, is included in the price of the room’](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/613707/484417), ‘in other words’ can't really substitute for ‘i.e.’.